# Combinations with restrictions in Python

Tags: python, combinations, restriction

I have a list

```py
S = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

and I want all combinations 3-by-3 without repetition but **with restrictions**: some elements cannot be in the same combination. Say, for example, that `A`, `B`, and `C` cannot be taken together: if there's `A` then `B` or `C` cannot belong to the combination, so in this case `[A, B, D]` is not a valid combination but `[A, D, E]` is valid.

I'm trying to code an algorithm (the list can be wider and we could have more restrictions).

What I've done for far is

```py
S = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
restricts = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["E", "F"]
]

COMBS = []

combs = list(combinations(S, 3))
# for each combination
for comb in combs:
    comb = list(comb)
    print("==> CHECKING", comb)
    valid = True
    # for each restriction
    for restrict in restricts:
        if not valid:
            break
        intersect = len(set(comb).intersection(set(restrict)))
        print("intersect", comb, restrict, "=", intersect)
        # if more than an element
        if intersect > 1:
            valid = False
    print("valid:", valid)
    if valid:
        COMBS.append(comb)
            
print("\nValid combinations:")
print(COMBS)
```

And it's working

```
Valid combinations:
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'D', 'F'], ['B', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'D', 'F'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'D', 'F']]
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better/faster way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a shorter/nicer code then you can use this list comprehension:

```
combs = [
    comb for comb in combinations(S, 3)
    if all(len(set(comb).intersection(r)) < 2 for r in restricts)
]
```

You could also represent restrictions in a different way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_restricts = defaultdict(set)
for restrict in restricts:
    r = set(restrict)
    for x in restrict:
        r.remove(x)
        new_restricts[x].update(r)
        r.add(x)

combs = [
    comb for comb in combinations(S, 3)
    if all(len(new_restricts[x].intersection(comb)) < 2 for x in comb)
]
```

In this way, you need at most 3 intersections.

Comment: Thanks, the list comprehension is perfect. I guess there isn't a shorter/faster way than this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?   Pretty much does the same as your code (though my comments are lacking)

```
for comb in combinations(S, 3):
    if all(len(set(comb).intersection(r)) < 2 for r in restricts):
        COMBS.append(list(comb))
```