# generating combinations with grouping restriction in python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I was trying to get all combinations of elements in disjoint sets, but there should only be one element of those sets at a time. Say for the matrix (where rows are elements and columns are the sets):

```
    s1   s2   s3
1 | 1  | 0  | 0  -> element 1 in set 1
2 | 1  | 0  | 0  -> element 2 in set 1
3 | 0  | 1  | 0  -> element 3 in set 2
4 | 0  | 1  | 0  -> element 4 in set 2
5 | 0  | 0  | 1  -> element 5 in set 3
6 | 0  | 0  | 1  -> element 6 in set 3
```

We can get the possible combinations as:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 -> element
___________
1 0 1 0 1 0 -> combination 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 -> combination 2
1 0 0 1 1 0 -> combination 3
1 0 0 1 0 1 -> combination 4
0 1 1 0 1 0 -> combination 5
0 1 1 0 0 1 -> combination 6
0 1 0 1 1 0 -> combination 7
0 1 0 1 0 1 -> combination 8
```

Where each row represents a combination of elements that exists in the sets 1 to 3.

I have tried a brute-force approach [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Czc.png)]([Combinations with restrictions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191528/combinations-with-restrictions-in-python)) where we generate all combinations then remove the invalid combinations in the list. I was wondering if there are quicker ways to do this?

```
comb_count, active_count = get_combination_count(self.sets)
temp_comb_count = comb_count
set_combinations = np.zeros((int(comb_count), len(self.sets)))

for index_m, set in enumerate(self.sets):
    if self.get_num_elements(set) == 0:
        continue
    
    indices = self.get_active_elements(set)
    amount = temp_comb_count/active_count[index_m]
    repeats = comb_count/temp_comb_count
    
        index_i = 0
    for index_k in range(int(repeats)):
        for index_j in indices:
            counter = 0
            while counter < amount:
                set_combinations[index_i, index_j] = 1
                counter = counter + 1
                index_i = index_i + 1

    temp_comb_count /= active_count[index_m]
```

Here is attempt for a quicker computation for the set of all possible combinations.

[2 Sets and 3 Elements - 1 element not in any set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Czc.png)

[2 Sets and 4 Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuBB1.png)

Comment: Why are `1 0 1 0 1 0` and `1 0 1 0 0 1` in the result, but `1 0 1 0 0 0` is not? Also, please share the code of what you tried, as this will be a good starting point for an answer that's actually useful to you, as well as providing a better understanding of your logic.

Comment: For the first question, I would only like to consider combinations that there is one element that came from any of the sets. I have updated the question to include my attempt. It assumes ```self.sets``` to be a 2d array where columns represents the sets and rows represents if the element is within that set.

Comment: Is it always the case that each number is only in one set (like 1 being only in s1), or is that just a bad example? In other words, are your sets always disjoint?

Comment: Your answer to my initial question is not clear - can you (in the question itself perhaps, the comments are not great for adding information) explain why `1 0 1 0 0 0` (as an example) is not in the result?

Comment: Do you just want the Cartesian product of some sets?

Comment: Just to clarify, in your example, you've just writting out `s1={1,2}`, `s2={3,4}`, and `s3={5,6}` in a less easy to read table form, and now you want all sets of size `len([s1,s2,s3])` with one element from each of those base sets, so one element from s1, one element from s2, and one element from s3? I.e. your "combination 1" is just `c1 ={1,3,5}`, "combination 6" is `c6 = {2,3,6}` etc? Because not using sets but just lists would make that a lot easier.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes that is exactly it. Pardon the format I gave. The format is actually given like that since, for my use case, I would like to use it for a computational model (https://doi.org/10.1109/TNNLS.2020.3005538) without representing the model in a linear way. I generalized the question, but specifically, the elements would be functions that can activate in a specific neuron (set) for a specific system configuration, which gives it its disjoint nature. The reason why ```1 0 1 0 0 0``` cannot be included is because there is an element that can activate for the second set.

Comment: I suggest representing your sets as suggested, `s1={1,2}; s2={3,4},;and s3={5,6}`. Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) or your own Cartesian product function to generate the product. Then convert the result back to the form you like. For the conversion from and to the form you like to the set notation, you can either write your own functions (there's really no difficulty for that part), or use a function from [scikit-learn's Preprocessing module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features)

Comment: Not sure I understand the explanation for `1 0 1 0 0 0`: that would be the set {1,3} so one element from s1 and one from s2, no problems there, but it's not a set of length 3, and lacks an element from s3, so _that_ I would imagine is the reason it's not in the list? All the sets in your list of valid combinations have elements from s2. That said: what is the actual code that defines your starting sets? Because I assume it's not "a text file table that you read in"? Can you update the post to show what `self.sets` is?